# Problems with resource injection in EJBs

Tags: java, jboss, ejb, jms

Im having troubles to get my connection factory using annotation resource.
It works well with the JNDI lookup but it does not with the annotation, my connection factory is null.

This is my code with the JNDI lookup (works) :

```
ConnectionFactory factory = (ConnectionFactory)context.lookup("/ConnectionFactory");
```

This is my code with the annotation :

```
@Resource(mappedName = "java:/ConnectionFactory")
private ConnectionFactory factory;
```

I ve tried with different mappedName as : /ConnectionFactory, java:/JmsXA, JmsXA etc. but still nullpointerexception :-/.

If someone has an idea ...

Thx !

This is my class :

```
@Stateless
public class ModuleCommunicationHandler implements IModuleCommunicationHandler
{

  /** The connection factory. */
  @Resource(mappedName = "java:/ConnectionFactory")
  private ConnectionFactory factory;

...........

/**
* {@inheritDoc}
*/
@Override
public void sendMessage(JMSMessage jmsMessage, int deliveryMode, int acknowledgeMode) throws TechnicalException
{

try
{
  context = new InitialContext();

  factory = (ConnectionFactory)context.lookup("/ConnectionFactory");

  // Setting the destination - Topic or Queue
  destination = (Destination)context.lookup(jmsMessage.getDestination());

  connection = factory.createConnection();
  session = connection.createSession(false, acknowledgeMode);

  sender = session.createProducer(destination);
  connection.start();

  // Creating the message
  message = session.createTextMessage();
  message.setText(jmsMessage.getBodyMessage());

  // Sending the message
  sender.setDeliveryMode(deliveryMode);
  sender.send(message);

.....
```

And this is the log :

```
15:05:32,609 ERROR [STDERR] com.*.*.*.server.exception.ModuleCommunicationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
15:05:32,609 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.*.*.*.server.service.ModuleCommunicationHandler.sendMessage(ModuleCommunicationHandler.java:147)
15:05:32,664 ERROR [STDERR] Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
15:05:32,664 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.*.*.*.server.service.ModuleCommunicationHandler.sendMessage(ModuleCommunicationHandler.java:108)
```

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing all your code (for the class in question) it's hard to say, but here's a few of the usual suspects:

1. The @Resource annotation instance does not specify a type, so it will default to the type of the field. If the actual resource is *a.b.c.ConnectionFactory*, but your field is *x.y.z.ConnectionFactory*, you would get an error of some sort.
2. Your annotated class may not be being deployed as a managed (injected) class. In other words, if you do not ensure that the class is treated as an EJB when deployed, the injection annotations will not be honored.  See [this post for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10438475/how-can-i-include-a-jms-producer-in-a-transaction-when-the-jms-prod-lives-in-a-h).

Do you not get any stack traces in your log when this happens ?

Comment: The error is thrown when I try to create a connection with my factory